# Why do these TShapes look so different?

Tags: delphi, graphics

[image]

Their design time properties are practically equal:

```
object ShpRectangle: TShape
  Left = 272
  Top = 96
  Width = 409
  Height = 473
  Brush.Style = bsClear
  Pen.Color = clWhite
  Pen.Mode = pmMaskPenNot
  Pen.Style = psDash
end
object ShpHorizontal: TShape
  Left = 221
  Top = 420
  Width = 500
  Height = 1
  Brush.Style = bsClear
  Pen.Color = clWhite
  Pen.Mode = pmMaskPenNot
  Pen.Style = psDash
end
object ShpVertical: TShape
  Left = 480
  Top = 50
  Width = 1
  Height = 540
  Brush.Style = bsClear
  Pen.Color = clWhite
  Pen.Mode = pmMaskPenNot
  Pen.Style = psDash
end
```

`ShpVertical.Width = 1` and `ShpHorizontal.Height = 1`, which might make them different from `ShpRectangle`, but they differ all three.
Can I make these TShapes look similar?

Note that I gave them `pmMaskPenNot/pmDash` because they serve as indicator lines overlaying a `TImage`.
(They still look like in the picture in that case).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here I have a form containing two `TShape` rectangles with dashed-dotted borders, one with height 9 px and the other with height 1 px, both having their widths animated:

[image: A screen recording of two shapes having their widths increased.]

As you might imagine, the "line" is actually composed of two lines -- a top border and a bottom border -- and its appearance depends on their phase difference which in turn depends on the width.

There's really not much you can do about it.

In any case, it is not a good idea to create a picture by combining VCL controls. (Creating an animation by doing so is even worse!) Instead, draw the picture manually using GDI, GDI+, or Direct2D. All these APIs have very easy-to-use methods to draw lines. Using GDI+ and Direct2D you can even draw non-solid thick lines.

Here's a GDI example:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin

  Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clBlack;

  Canvas.Pen.Style := psDashDot;
  Canvas.MoveTo(10, ClientHeight div 2);
  Canvas.LineTo(Round(10 + (ClientWidth - 20) * Abs(Sin(x))), ClientHeight div 2);

  Canvas.Pen.Style := psDash;
  Canvas.MoveTo(10, ClientHeight div 2 - 5);
  Canvas.LineTo(Round(10 + (ClientWidth - 20) * Abs(Sin(x))), ClientHeight div 2 - 5);

  Canvas.Pen.Style := psDot;
  Canvas.MoveTo(10, ClientHeight div 2 + 5);
  Canvas.LineTo(Round(10 + (ClientWidth - 20) * Abs(Sin(x))), ClientHeight div 2 + 5);

  x := x + 0.01;

end;
```

A `TTimer` invalidates the form 30 times per second or so.

[image: Screen recording of lines drawn manually using GDI]